# How to make a 3D modelling interface just like VRoid Studio

Tags: user-interface, 3d, avatar, 3d-modelling, avatar-generation

I would like to make a 3D modelling interface, where I can adjust the parameters of the 3D avatars. An example would be like VRoid Studio (https://vroid.com/en/studio), having sliders to change the body areas.

Any idea for me to start with? Appreciate if someone can provide some tools or starter kits on this issue.